# Can I use Windows Azure as a DDoS shield?

Tags: azure, ddos

I have a server that is in an unprotected facility, without any kind of DDoS protection. My question is how can I use a Windows Azure service in order to protect my server from DDoS attacks?

Comment: you have to stick it behind a firewall.

Comment: can i stick it behind something built in windows azure?

Comment: sticking it behind azure is worthless.  If you put it out in the open unprotected then you will probably have at least 30K attacks on it by the end of the weekend.  You must put a firewall in front of azure.  There is no reason to NOT do that.  It is just pure common sense.  Kind of like asking can I put a fire extinguiser behind my can of gas as I expose it to 1000 matches -- will that protect me?